# Rails 3.1 load Modernizr before my application javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, modernizr

I've added modernizr-rails to my rails project, and it seems to load fine (I can access Modernizr in a debug javascript console). According to the [documentation](https://github.com/russfrisch/modernizr-rails#usage), I added the include tag to the html head section like so:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :modernizr %>
```

But it seems to load after my application javascript file (`app/assets/javascripts/app.js`), causing any reference to it to fail.

It's a mostly fresh new rails project, is there anything I'm missing? Or am I meant to wait for the document loaded event before calling Modernizr anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, yes there was something missing. I had put the `javascript_include_tag :modernizr` code in my template, rather than the application layout (`app/views/layouts/application`), which defines the html head for all templates in the app.